# How Can Show InterAd After X Clicks?

Tags: java, button, onclick, admob, interstitial

**How can show the interstitial ads  after 2 button clicks in this code java ?
"Lastes SDK Admob  20.2.0"**

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Button 1 Clicked");

            if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
                save_id(btn1.getId());
                mInterstitialAd.show(main_activity.this);
            }
            else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet");

                Intent intent = new Intent(main_activity.this, getstarted.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a variable like `clickCount` and everytime its `even value` ie. `modulo by 2 == 0` you could show the ad right?

`int clickCount = 0`;

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Button 1 Clicked");
        clickCount++;
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && (clickCount % 2 == 0)) {
            clickCount = 0;
            save_id(btn1.getId());
            mInterstitialAd.show(main_activity.this);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet or the button was only clicked once");

            Intent intent = new Intent(main_activity.this, getstarted.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if it worked, please consider accepting the answer as the correct answer!